# Posting to a page's feed with mentions, the mentions are filtered out

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, tagging

When posting a message with a status including a mention, such as "Message with @[id:Mention]", the message appears on the page with the mention removed, in this case as "Message with ".

Is posting a mention to a page with a page not supported through open graph?

Thank you!